# Spring Data - JpaRepository using non-Primary EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've got two connections to the database in my application, one for Postgres, one for SQL Server. They use the same entity model and I want to use them to store same data in both databases.

I specify as beans appropriate `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` s, `PlatformTransactionManager` s, and `DataSource`s. I've got two set of repositories and I'd like one of them to use one database, and the other repository to use the second database. Yet both of my repositories are always use the `@Primary` set of the beans

I specify the package that contains either first or the second repository in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation of the `@Configuration` class containing the beans like below. I was hoping this will make sure that the wiring will happen correctly. What am I doing incorrectly?

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="dao.postgres",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManagerFactory"
)
public class PostgresDataSourceConfigurations {


  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.postgresql")
  public DataSourceProperties postgresqlDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }


  @Qualifier("postgresDataSource")
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public DataSource postgresqlDataSource() {
    return postgresqlDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "postgresEntityManagerFactory")
  @Primary
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
      EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("postgresDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .packages("profiles", "outbox")
        .persistenceUnit("postgresPersistenceUnit")
        .build();
  }
  @Bean(name = "postgresTransactionManager")
  @Primary
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
      @Qualifier("postgresEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
```

```
package dao.postgres;

import domain.Address;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.UUID;

public interface PostgresAddressDao extends CrudRepository<Address, UUID> {

}
```

Comment: You also need to tell the `@EnableJpaRepositories` which transaction manager to use. Also make sure that both transaction managers aren't named the same (preferably you rename the method as well). If that doesn't resolve the case how are you using the repositories please show the actual usage and please provide both configuration classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum you were first and your answer helped me solve the specific issue I had. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the transaction manager to be used by each `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. Additionally, ensure that the transaction managers have distinct names!

So first of all, update your `PostgresDataSourceConfigurations` class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "dao.postgres",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgresEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "postgresTransactionManager" //specify transaction manager
)
public class PostgresDataSourceConfigurations {
    //your codes in here
    
    @Bean(name = "postgresTransactionManager") //rename method to have a distinct name
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager postgresTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("postgresEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
    
    //your codes in here
}
```

then create a separate configuration class for the SQL Server:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "dao.sqlserver",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlServerEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "sqlServerTransactionManager" //specify transaction manager
)
public class SqlServerDataSourceConfigurations {
    //similar to PostgresDataSourceConfigurations
    
    @Bean(name = "sqlServerTransactionManager") //rename the method to have a distinct name
    public PlatformTransactionManager sqlServerTransactionManager(
        @Qualifier("sqlServerEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
    
    //similar to PostgresDataSourceConfigurations
}
```

as you see,each repository package will use the appropriate transaction manager, ensuring that the correct database connection is used!

Comment: Sorry, I first gave the answer and then saw the comment.
@M.Deinum had given the correct answer, and this answer is only here for future viewers who see this question. I would also appreciate it if M.Deinum could provide his answer as well, so that if my answer is incomplete, it can be made complete!

Answer (score -2):

By default, spring data JPA expects one datasource. If you configure two datasources, you'll get runtime error. You must annotate one of them as `@Primary` (you've already done that).

Now all repositories will use primary datasource unless you tell them otherwise. Annotate your service with this: `@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "secondaryTransactionManager")` and then you'll be able to access your secondary datasource.

Primary datasource service example:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PrimaryDatasourceService {

    @Nonnull private final MyPrimaryDataSourceModelRepository myPrimaryDataSourceModelRepository;

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<MyPrimaryDataSourceModel> readData() {
        return myPrimaryDataSourceModelRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void writeData(@Nonnull final MyPrimaryDataSourceModel data) {
        myPrimaryDataSourceModelRepository.save(data);
    }
}
```

Secondary datasource service example:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true, transactionManager = "secondaryTransactionManager")
public class SecondaryDatasourceService {

    @Nonnull private final MySecondaryDataSourceModelRepository mySecondaryDataSourceModelRepository;

    @Nonnull
    @Override
    public List<MySecondaryDataSourceModel> readData() {
        return mySecondaryDataSourceModelRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(transactionManager = "secondaryTransactionManager")
    public void writeData(@Nonnull final MySecondaryDataSourceModel data) {
        mySecondaryDataSourceModelRepository.save(data);
    }
}
```

**BTW, your primary and secondary models and repositories need to be separate and your datasource configurations must use appropriate packages in annotations** like this:

Primary datasource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.model.primary")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.example.repository.primary",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager"
)
public class PrimaryDataSourceConfiguration {
    // your @Primary annotated datasource, entityManager and transactionManager beans
}
```

Secondary datasource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.model.secondary")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.example.repository.secondary",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "secondaryEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "secondaryTransactionManager"
)
public class SecondaryDataSourceConfiguration {
    // your datasource, entityManager and transactionManager beans
}
```

Any JPA settings like `ddl-auto: update` or `show-sql: false` in your application.properties or application.yaml file, are common for both datasources. `ddl-auto: update` will make sure your DB reflects your models. So, if you do not separate your models and repositories, your datasource configurations will get messed up and your DB as well.